# MongoDB insert without duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Right now I am running mongodb and I just realized, I am inserting into collections and I am not sure if I am preventing duplicates. Here is how I am inserting:

```
function insertCompanies(companyID, companyURL, companyAppID) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("We are connected");
        }

        var collection = db.collection('Companies');
        var company = {
            "companyProfileID": companyID,
            "url": companyURL,
            "appID": companyAppID
        };
        collection.insert(company, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
        db.close();
    });
}
```

I am using NodeJS. When a user calls the `insertCompanies` method, if the company already exists (via `companyID` or `URL`), it seems like the collection allows duplicates.

Is there a different insert function that prevents duplicates? I looked around and could not find a straight forward solution tailored to me.

Comment: You can also add a unique index on field which will not allow duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `db.insert()` you should use `db.update()` and specify `$upsert: true`.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: We don't need to use update, please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61480444/7237613

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not to insert, instead use [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). The update() method either modifies the fields in existing documents or replaces an existing document entirely.