# Post data in mongoDB without duplication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to save data to my data  base, but I want to avoid duplication.

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664404/mongodb-insert-without-duplicates) however  `db.update({upsert:true})`dosen't solve the problem. In each case (new element, duplicated element) is returns in body:

> {
>       "ok": 0,
>       "n": 0,
>       "nModified": 0
>   }

So I have decided to check in POST whether given body already exist in my database.

This is my code right now:

```
var query = req.body._links;
 //check is given body is in db
 Note.findOne({"_links":query}).then(note => {

    if(note){
        console.log("This has already been saved");
    } else {

        // Create a Note
      const note = new Note({
            _links: req.body._links,
            });

// Save Note in the database
note.save()
.then(data => {
    res.send(data);
}).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Note."
    });
});

    }
});
```

But it always adds the element.

That's the schema:

```
_links : {
self :   { href : String},
    subscription : [
        {href : String,
        rel  : String}
         ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your query simply isn't structured to find the potentially existing doc you're looking to capture. Place a `console.log` in your `if` statement, to ensure that your query is finding the existing doc. If it doesn't make it into that portion of the conditional `if` block, then you know your query is incorrect.

Comment: note is always empty after the `if`. But when I `find` the element by sub element of _links (_links.self.href) it is ok. So as far as I understand i can't query by object?