# MongoDB insertMany and skip duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to [`insertMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) items into my Mongo database but I would like to skip duplicate IDs.
I'm using `Node.js` and [`mongodb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb).

I have some data:

```js
const myExampleData = [
   {_id:'someId1', name:'I am example'},
   {_id:'someId2', name:'I am second example'}
];
```

and I would like to insert them like this:

```js
dbo.collection(collectionName).insertMany(myExampleData).catch(err=>{
    console.error(err);
});
```

Lets suppose that `someId1` already exists. I don't want to override it. I just want to skip it. In current situation it doesn't insert `someId2`. It stops as soon as it throws duplicate exception.

**Is there a way how to insertMany and skip duplicates?**

---

#### Possible question duplicate.

I've found thread [MongoDB insert without duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664404/mongodb-insert-without-duplicates) where is suggested to use [`update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) with [`upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#syntax) instead of [`insert()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) which could be fine for one item. But how about many items? As far as I know [`updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) would update all filtered rows with the same value but I would like to insert different values.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Checking in your statement :

> Lets suppose that someId1 already exists. I don't want to override it.
>   I just want to skip it.

So you just wanted to skip duplicate docs as your intention is not update duplicate docs with latest data - So there is no need to use `.update()`, You can still do this using [.insertMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/index.html) by passing in a flag `ordered` in options to query :

**Ordered :** Optional. A boolean specifying whether the **mongod** instance should perform an ordered or unordered insert. Defaults to **true**.

```
db.collection.insertMany(
   [ <document 1> , <document 2>, ... ],
   {
     ordered: <boolean>
   }
)
```

**Your code :**

```
dbo.collection(collectionName).insertMany(myExampleData, {ordered : false }).catch(err=>{
    console.error(err);
})
```

As if you're checking against `_id` which will have default unique index & any incoming duplicates will actually throw an error, With `ordered : false` we're making this insertion operation un-ordered by that we're skipping all the incoming duplicates & proceeding further with out actually throwing any errors.

Comment: It works fine. Thank you. You wrote _proceeding further without actually throwing any errors_. But actually it still throws errors. There are all of the duplicates logged in `err.writeErrors`. As is written in documentation, just for clarification: _Excluding Write Concern errors, ordered operations stop after an error, while **unordered operations continue to process any remaining write operations** in the queue._

Comment: @Jax-p : My intention is when I say - *with out actually throwing any errors* - means without blocking actual insertion operation will proceed with further insertion of rest of the docs, Yes you can find those ids which are not inserted will be logged for future reference.. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use bulkWrite to perform the operation and get similar result. For example, in mongo shell:

```
   db.collectionName.bulkWrite(
      [
         { updateOne :
            {
               "filter" : { _id:'someId1'},
               "update" : { $set : { name:'I am example'}},
               "upsert" : true
            }
         },
        { updateOne :
            {
               "filter" : { _id:'someId2' },
               "update" : { $set : { name:'I am second example'} },
              "upsert" : true
            }
         },
      ]
   );
```

Running the above will only insert two documents first time it ran. And won't give you any errors on subsequent runs.

Comment: I solved my problem! insertMany() only works on console but not API / serverless.

Comment: @benone what do you mean with `insertMany()` does not work in serverless? Can you give an example? I use mongo `insert` in a [serverless function](https://github.com/tik9/fun/blob/main/functions/mongo.js) with netlify.

Comment: @benone: your assumption is incorrect! All SDks should support`.insertMany()` irrespective whether you use in traditional server/serverless! We were using serverless & `insertmany()` without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of Yahya's answer, if you wish to only insert non-duplicates, and completly skip updaing existing documents, use `@setOnInsert`

```
   db.collectionName.bulkWrite(
      [
         { updateOne :
            {
               "filter" : { name: 'I am example' }, // the 'deduplication' filter, can be any property, not just _id
               "update" : { $setOnInsert : { name:'I am example', something: 'else' }},
               "upsert" : true
            }
         },
        { updateOne :
            {
               "filter" : { name: 'I am example' },
               "update" : { $setOnInsert : { name:'I am second example', more: 'properties' } },
              "upsert" : true
            }
         },
      ]
   );
```

So with the above code ran, on the first go, both documents will be inserted.
on the second go, only the second document will be inserted, as the filter criteria matches an already existing document, the first one.
this also works for duplicate documents passed to the same bulk operation, as long as they match on the 'deduplication' filter criteria.

With `@setOnInsert`, upsert will actually not update the first existing document on the second run.

So in essence you achieve: "insert many in one query. create non existing according to match (filter) criteria, and dont update existing"